# Undefined property: stdClass::$1 trying to retrieve POST

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to access a post input value in my controller. Any help finding out what I am doing wrong here ?

**Here is my Controller**

```
class Login extends MY_Controller {


public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Users_model');
    $this->load->helper('form_helper');
}


public function index()
{

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('login');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function authenticate(){
    if($this->input->post('submit')){
        $id  = $this->input->post('id');

    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id));

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
       echo $row->$id;
       echo $row->email;
       echo $row->password;
    }

    }


}
```

}

**The Login Form**

```
<?php echo form_open('login/authenticate') ?>

<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="input" name="id"/><br/>



<input type="submit" name="submit"  />
```

*The above code gives an error as*

> A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$1

Filename: controllers/login.php

Thanks, any help much appreciated. :)

Comment: What result or error are you getting? What does it do instead of what you expect it to do?

Comment: This:  `echo $row->$id;` remove that `$` from `id`.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBerkowski, I am trying to access the post input "id" from within the controller and retrieve the row from db which corresponds to the value. I am getting an error, but the query results are retrieved. How can I clear the error ?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBerkowski. That cleared the error. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try change `echo $row->$id;` to `echo $row->id;`

Answer (score 0):

Why when relating the model an error occurs ?

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'post.karyawan_model_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `post` where `post`.`karyawan_model_id` = 1 and `post`.`karyawan_model_id` is not null)'

Model postingan:

```php
class PostinganModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'post';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['id','id_users','postingan','create'];


    public function Karyawan(){
        return $this->BelongsTo(KaryawanModel::class);
    }
}

class KaryawanModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['id','name', 'email', 'email_verified_at','password','remember_token','created_at','update_at'];
    public function Postingan(){
        return $this->hasMany(PostinganModel::class);
    }
}
```